# What is the alternate to posexplode() in Spark Sql as it doesn't take variable number of arguments dynamically?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

```
val result = df.select($"seq_id", posexplode(array($"prod_id", $"prod_name")))
```

In above example posexplode doesn't take any sequence of column names in side array(). It is mandatory to hardcode the column names. Is there any way to remove hardcoding and add any number of columns dynamically?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want to rename the columns from posexplode, i.e., change "pos" and "col" to some other column names?

Comment: Can I pass "pos" and "col" in form of any variable? Because I want to write one generic code and don't want to hardcode values. I mean if required I should be able to send 4 columns with out writing each of the column names inside array(). If it is not possible then could you suggest anything else other than posexplode()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the function [declaration](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala) `array(cols: Column*): Column` we can pass one or more col as parameters for the array function. This can be done also dynamically by generating an array of columns from an arbitrary string list:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{posexplode, col, array}

val cols = Seq("prod_id", "prod_name").map{col(_)}
val customArray = array(cols:_*)

df.select(customArray).show
```

This will enclose `prod_id, prod_name` into an array and it uses `array` function as you previously did.